# Why isn't bottom:0 working even when I use position relative?

Tags: css

I've got some bars that are currently aligned at the top of my page, but for some reason I can't seem to get them aligned at the bottom of the page instead.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgb(75, 71, 71);
    display: inline-flex;
}

.bar {
    height: 200px;
    width: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    outline: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sorting Visulizer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/random.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have `bottom: 0;` on the bars, but they are still aligned at the top. I've tried adding `position: absolute;` to the bars and `position: relative;` to the wrapper, but it doesn't seem to work. All it does it just put all of the bars on top of each other so it looks like just one bar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: only `top` `left` properties have influence when using position relative

Comment: Oh okay, would there be a way for me to align the bars on the bottom of the screen then? All the bars would be varying heights, this was just a sample I put together for the question

Comment: That is not true, @ZohirSalak.

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot, i'm fuzzy on this, it's the opposites that doesn't have influence. Like if you have a left value the right won't have an effect `top left` take priority over `right bottom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the positioning of flex items via [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) and/or [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

For example, adding `align-items: flex-end` to `.wrapper` does what I *think* you're trying to do:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgb(75, 71, 71);
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 2px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! Didn't know about flex-end, I will keep that in mind for the future.